# Jenkins build promotion: How do I schedule a build promotion?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

Is it possible to schedule a build promotion?

Comment: Are you talking about https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin, and if so, what have you tried?

Comment: Yes, is it. 
I know I can schedule a build with crontab but I have not found a way to schedule a promotion

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of is to create a second upstream job, lets call it the 'Scheduled Promotion Job'

In the Scheduled Promotion job create a promotion which has the promote immediately once the build completes, and schedule it's build to run according to the schedule you want the downstream job to be promoted by.

In the actual downstream build tell it to promote when the following upstream promotions are promoted, and enter the job name of the Scheduled Promotion Job.

To put it another way, tell your build to watch up upstream job for promptions, and put the schedule in the upstream job.

I just tried this with some test projects on my test jenkins server and it worked a treat.

Comment: I've been thinking of a similar solution to what you proposed, but can't see a way to do this without side-effects?  Is there a way to chain jobs together but not have upstream ALWAYS execute downstream when it completes?